# what do we call small problems with others?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word in English that is used to describe the tiny issues that you have with others? I've searched and find words such as hitch but not sure if I can use it in the social context (e.g., I have a hitch with my advisor).

Comment: A minor issue? A slight disagreement? A bit of a personality clash? A small difference of opinion? There are a lot of phrases all meaning slightly different things but I can't think of a one-word term. It's unlikely that 'hitch' is quite right but the exact choice of phrase would depend on the nature of the 'hitch'.

Comment: I see no reason to close this question. It deals with word choice from large vocabularies, and with appropriate usage. Have I missed something?)

Comment: Please edit your post to do both of the following two things. First, show us which words or phrases you've already considered in your previous research but ended up discarding, along with why you found each of those unsuitable. Second, show us a few examples of how you might use this term in a broader sentence. We need to understand if you're looking for a noun or a verb or an adjective, or even something else.

Answer (score 0):

*Niggle* is a candidate for this.

“A small doubt or worry”

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/niggle)